# Manually compiled TigerVNC throws syntax error on Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, vnc, raspberry-pi, vncserver

I want to set up TigerVNC (because it have XRandR support), on my Raspberry Pi B+. So I've downloaded sources from TigerVNC Github repo and compiled directly on Raspberry using CMake. It compiled successfully, so all dependencies are met. When I start server it throws me that:

```
Could not start Xvnc.

/usr/local/bin/Xvnc: 1: /usr/local/bin/Xvnc: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
```

Before occuring that error it told me that, TigerVNC can't find Xvnc binary, so I copied it:

```
vncserver: couldn't find "/usr/local/bin/Xvnc".
cp /usr/bin/Xvnc /usr/local/bin/Xvnc
```

After issuing cp command I ended up with first error. I tried also to run TigerVNC manually:

```
Xvnc
-bash: /usr/local/bin/Xvnc: cannot execute binary file
```

Using file prints that:

```
Xvnc: ERROR: cannot open `Xvnc' (No such file or directory)
```

Running as root does not change anything.

EDIT:
Commands:

```
ls -l /usr/local/bin/Xvnc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1225600 Dec 21 16:43 /usr/local/bin/Xvnc
 file /usr/local/bin/Xvnc
 /usr/local/bin/Xvnc: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.4.0, stripped
 ldd /usr/local/bin/Xvnc
 not a dynamic executable
```

Why it is 64-bit executable? Raspberry CPU is 32-bit ARM BCM2835, also why it is not dynamic? I compiled it using cmake with dynamic linking not static.

Comment: What do these commands give: `ls -l /usr/local/bin/Xvnc`, `file /usr/local/bin/Xvnc`, `ldd /usr/local/bin/Xvnc` ?

Comment: Added output of these commands

Comment: Did You compiled TigerVNC on PC and transfered it to Rpi? `ldd` shows it is x86_64 binary. If so - it won't work - RPi is not x86_64, but ARM CPU.

Comment: No, I compiled it directly on Raspi using CMake. So this is even more weird what happened.

Comment: What exactly did You downloaded? Maybe it already contained some binaries (compiled for different architecture)? Does this `Xvnc` work on Your PC (if it is x86_64)?

Comment: Okay I cloned TigerVNC sources from GitHub repo: https://github.com/TigerVNC/tigervnc and as usual started CMake and compiled it.

Comment: From https://github.com/TigerVNC/tigervnc/blob/master/BUILDING.txt it seems with cmake You can build client only (not Xvnc). I assume Xvnc binary, whic You have copied has nothing todo with Your TigerVNC build (how/when it got to /usr/bin ? ).

Comment: So why I got these binaries. I didn't install them, because they are not in repo

Comment: I don't know **when** You got this Xvnc. You can try moving `/usr/bin/Xvnc` and rebuilding/reinstalling TigerVNC (as You did before). My guess You won't get `/usr/bin/Xvnc` recreated.

Comment: Yeah, It looks that I wilk stay wit TightVnc